# if statements, comparing lists, python

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

what am i doing wrong with my if statement that it doesn't recognise if an element in a is equal to 0? what i am attempting to print is for ever 0 the program prints `.` and for ever 1 `#`. cheers.

```
a=[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
print(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]==[0]:
        print('.', end='')
    else:
        print('#', end='')
print()
```

bash:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
##############
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
if a[i] == 0:
```

instead of

```
if a[i] == [0]:
```

You want to compare the items to the integer value `0`, not to the single-element list `[0]`.

Comment: oh yes, thankyou. before when i kept on testing i kept getting not iterable. Im new to programing so its hard to remember what i trying before.

Comment: this raises a rhetorical question.
why does a[1] return an integer
while a[1:2] return a list. 
i suppose it doesnt matter why, but its interesting to note and the reason for my confusion. cheers

Comment: @JensD: A slicing `a[i:j]` returns a sublist of length `j - i`.  If this difference is one, you get a sublist of length 1.  It would be inconsistent if you would get the item itself.